# Is the encryption status of a backup logged in macOS?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I am running macOS Sierra (10.12) and I lost a backup I made in May 2019. I am not sure if it was encrypted or not.

Is there a way to find out if it was encrypted? Is that logged somewhere in the macOS?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth checking in the prefs... System prefs > Time Machine > Select Disk...

If the drive is remembered in there it should say below whether backups are encrypted or not. [I can't test for a missing drive, it shows for mine in situ, even without the actual drive selected.]

[image]

Comment: The USB Drive is not visible there anymore :-( any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no - that was all I had.

Comment: So basically, the USB hard drive is missing—stolen, misplace, lost, etc…—and you want to confirm if it was encrypted via your system’s current OS?